# onhashchange reloads page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

Is that correct? I was thinking it was just an event that fired when the page refreshed. I did a basic `document.write` and did `i++` whenever onhashchange was triggered but it always is at 0 and i lose all my other vars and stuff. I also tried return false, but nothing.

Am i doing it wrong? Or is onhashchange supposed to reset the page? If so, can you stop it but still fire the callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that Web Inspector is super buggy with this. For example, multiple console.log()s in a `onhashchange` rewrite the same console.log(). Also, i noticed that sometimes the console would just go completely blank when changing pages. I discovered it's bugginess when I put a timer on the page and noticed the timer was incrementing but the console was showing blank or misinformation.

Answer (score 1):

No `onHashChange` merely fires whenever the # portion of a url is changed, this is client-side only and the page should not reload when doing so. `document.write` however can clobber your global variables.

If you need more help we'll need more to go on.